# How using 32 bit dll for AnyCPU?

Tags: c#, windows, dll, com

How can I use 32 dll for AnyCpu(x64). Error :

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {E187099F-8C5C-4723-8866-D8DBB6353ADE} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040153 Invalid value for registry (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040153 (REGDB_E_INVALIDVALUE))

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: No. You cannot use 32bit dlls in an 64bit application.

A workaround would be to create a 32bit application, that uses the 32bit dll and then communicates with your 64bit application via IPC or something similar.